# Windows 10 sleep keeps waking up

Tags: windows-10

I've got the latest Windows 10 installed on my multi-monitor system.  I can put windows to sleep from my start menu (power/sleep) and the monitors power off and I can hear the computer itself go to sleep.

It always seems to wake up on it's own shortly there after.  How can I make it sleep more soundly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run cmd as

```
   powercfg -lastwake
```

The output  tells you which device woke the computer.

Comment: thanks, @oussema Aroua. I'm also trying powercfg -devicequery wake_armed to see the list but it's hard to tell which keyboard mouse is witch with multiple attached.

Comment: Is the "-1" vote because I'm asking in the wrong place? I can't seem to find any docs on where the right place would be topost if this is the case.

Comment: hhh don't know why you had that -1, for your problem just stop these devices from waking your computer in the Device Manager

Comment: @PeterKellner: quite sure, yes. Ask on SuperUser instead

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWeller.  I will next time.